# What is the recommended way to support multiple languages in my C# program?

Tags: c#

I'm about to start a desktop program that I want to add support for as many languages as I can. I'm going to be using C# and at least .Net 2.0. Is there a recommended way for adding support for multiple languages in the GUI and error messages?

Many thanks

Comment: Go slow, add just one language at first to see what kind of effort it takes.  It isn't trivial.

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty of localization articles on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cptutorials/html/introduction_to_resources_and_localization.asp

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k15k55d.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/getwr/dotneti18n.mspx

Answer (score 2):

The umbrella term that applies to this is **localization**, specifically string localization (other things like currency and date/time formats can be localized, too). [Here's a tutorial that covers some important aspects of it.](http://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=211)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, Take a look at [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) for constructing the parallel resx files